# Putting a PowerPoint and Video together

Tags: software-recommendation, video, iwork, keynote, ms-office

What is the easiest way to take a powerpoint or keynote presentation and a video of me giving the presentation and put the two together so that they can always see the slides and my video of me giving the presentation.

It would be nice if I could zoom into each and shrink the other has I wanted to focus on the slide or the presentation, but just being able to put the two side by side would be good enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know if you can do that with the presentation itself (a Keynote document being “played”) but if you can make a movie (hint: in Keynote you can record your presentation) of the slides (so they become a Quicktime movie and not a set of slideshows), you can later use any movie edition software (not iMovie) to create the desired effect.

An expensive but very powerful one is [BoinxTV](http://boinx.com/boinxtv/overview/). It’s really powerful and easy to use, but doesn’t support using a keynote as a source, only different types of images, sound and video.

Of course Final Cut (pro and express) would be able to do that too.

As good as these solutions may seem, they are not real time, in a sense where you can be giving the presentation while you receive a live video feed of you being recorded and dynamically decide to “zoom” into the slide. That is much more complex.

Now if you can edit and post-produce the slides and you giving the presentation, those tools will probably suite you.

Comment: Post Production is fine.  I'll look into each thing you've mentioned.

Comment: If you try BoinxTV, I suggest you take a look at the templates to see how it works; it’s not difficult, but the “power” is often hidden until you see a real case. The templates are excellent ones. :)

Comment: You can use iMovie Picture in Picture mode to do that, even if post-production can be really painful.

Comment: @Roberto and by “can be really painful” you really mean: it’s going to be a nightmare to do what you really want, unless you really want something simple. ;)

Comment: The main problem is that you can't really split clips in picture-in-picture mode. Audio synchronization is also a pain. But for very simple things it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

You have several possibilities.

The easiest for you would be probably be using [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm). It allows you to record what happens on the screen (the presentation) AND the camera input. It also allows you to do some simple post-production, like focusing on the screen or on the camera.